# Relación uno a uno MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli, mysql-workbench

estoy teniendo un problema a la hora de crear una tabla.

La creo, y luego con el programa MySQL Workbench creo un diagrama con 
la ingeniería reversa y me salen relaciones de uno a muchos en las 
tres tablas que he creado, y lo que realmente busco es una relacion de
uno a uno.
Aquí pongo las sentencias y en seguida la imagen.

```
/*Borramos la base de datos si esta ya existe*/
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS gameDB;

/*Creamos la base de datos*/
CREATE DATABASE gameDB;
USE gameDB;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS usuario(
id_user int(16)NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
username varchar(16)NOT NULL UNIQUE,
nombre varchar(32)NOT NULL,
apellido varchar(64)NOT NULL,
email varchar(64)NOT NULL UNIQUE,
password varchar(64)NOT NULL,
fecha_alta DATETIME NOT NULL,
ultima_conexion DATETIME,
CONSTRAINT PK_id_user PRIMARY KEY (id_user)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS alianza(
id_alianza int(16)NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
nombre varchar(32)NOT NULL UNIQUE,
id_lider int(16)NOT NULL UNIQUE ,
CONSTRAINT PK_id_alianza PRIMARY KEY (id_alianza)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_info(
id_user int(16)NOT NULL UNIQUE,
raza varchar(32)NOT NULL,
id_alianza int(16) default null ,
FOREIGN KEY (id_alianza) REFERENCES alianza(id_alianza)ON DELETE SET NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (id_user) REFERENCES usuario(id_user)ON DELETE CASCADE
);

ALTER TABLE alianza
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_id_lider
FOREIGN KEY (id_lider) REFERENCES user_info(id_user)ON DELETE RESTRICT;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Que podría hacer para intentar solventar ese problema?

obs: Una alianza solo tiene un lider, y un lider solo puede ser lider de una alianza. 
Un usuario puede pertenecer a una alianza o no, y varios usuarios pueden estar en la misma alianza.

Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Mi pregunta es desde donde estas creando tus tablas desde mysql.?.. si ese es el caso te sugiero usar mysql Worbench una vez que diseñas tu base de datos esta la puedes pasar a mysql directamente

Comment: Una alianza puede tener muchos usuarios debes verlo de esta forma y entender que el líder es un características de rango

Comment: @Tegito123 Los lanzo desde la consola de MySQL.Nunca probe crear tablas de manera gráfica, quizas sea la solucion.

Comment: @JackNavaRow  Y como le doy a entender al programa quien es el lider de esa alianza? No veo otra forma de guadar esa información.

Comment: @Wolobi esa es precisamente unas de las funcionalidades de MysqlWorbench, ver o realizar de manera grafica tu BD, modificar, editar, eliminar y posteriormente sincronizar con MYSQL..cada vez que requieras realizar cambios en tus campos o tablas lo harias de Worbench y luego lo sincronizas y listo.... !!

Comment: Si muchos usuarios pueden pertenecer a la misma alianza, la relación alianza->user_info es uno a muchos. Por otro lado, `user_info` debiera tener llave primaria en `id_user`. ¿Qué relaciones específicamente quieres que sean 1:1?

Comment: @amenadiel Quiero que sean 1:1 la de id_user entre la tabla usuario y la tabla user_info, y luego tbn quiero que sea 1:1 el user_id de user_info y id_lider de alianza. gracias, intente hacerlo desde WBench y cuando exporto el codigo me siguen saliendo 1:N, gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Para lo primero, probaste poner llave primaria user_id en user_info? Para lo segundo, podrías probar usar el id_lider como primaria y referenciar la tabla principal de usuario, total es único, no nulo y necesariamente está en la tabla de usuarios

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Es una pregunta interesante. Con una respuesta que espero también lo sea :-)

Básicamente MySQL Workbench, haciendo ingeniería inversa, pinta las relaciones como 1-N porque no puede distinguirlas de una 1-1 porque ¡ambas se implementan de la misma manera!

(bueno, siendo justos, las relaciones 1-1 son más flexibles porque la fk se pueden 'heredar' hacia cualquiera de las dos tablas implicadas)

Pero el caso es que solamente viendo la estructura de las tablas y sin saber nada más, es imposible saber si una relación es 1-1 o 1-N.

Te propongo una prueba: Dada esta definición de bbdd (sobre hospitales y directores)

```
create table hospital (
  id_hospital integer primary key,
  nombre varchar(255)
);

create table director (
  id_director integer primary key,
  nombre varchar(255),
  fk_dirige_hospital integer
);

ALTER TABLE director
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_dirige_hospital
FOREIGN KEY (fk_dirige_hospital)
REFERENCES hospital(id_hospital)
ON DELETE RESTRICT;
```

¿Puedes decirme si la relación entre hospital y director es 1-1 o 1-N? ¿Un hospital podría tener varios directores, o solamente uno? La verdad es que únicamente mirando la estructura nunca lo podríamos saber. Una relación 1-1 se podría entender como un caso especial de una relación 1-N

Aún así, hay maneras de mejorar la estructura y forzar una 1-1.

Por ejemplo, puedo agregar un índice UNIQUE para la columna fk. De esta manera, en la tabla de director nunca se podría repetir el mismo valor para fk_dirige_hospital, lo que viene a significar que es imposible que más de un director dirija el mismo hospital.

Ojo, que este apaño podría no funcionar en otras bases de datos. La mayoría se quejarían al encontras varios valores null. No sería problema si la columna es not null, pero en cualquier caso es una solución que podría no ser portable y dificilmente se podría considerar como un estándard.

Pese a todo e incluso con apaños, el problema para Mysql Workbench es el mismo. A nivel de constraint, son iguales y por lo tanto indistinguibles.

Quizás en versiones futuras lo mejoren y se puedan fijar que si una fk tiene un índice UNIQUE, probablemente la relación sea 1-1. O quizás nunca quieran asumir este caso porque no se trata de una solución estándard.

Otra opción es que tu mismo puedas cambiar el diagrama una vez generados, pero por mi parte desconozco si lo puedes hacer.

**Extra:**

Se podría incluso decir que (*a nivel de implementación en base de datos*) las únicas relaciones que existen son las 1-N.

Como sabrás, las relaciones N-N se acaban descomponiendo en 1-N + N-1 con una tabla intermedia.

Y por otro lado, las relaciones 1-1 se pueden considerar como un caso especial de las 1-N

Comment: Gracias por el tiempo tomado en elaborar esta magnifica respuesta.